Movie where a kid dies at grandfather's house and comes back
I suddenly remembered a scene from a movie and can't for the life of me remember what movie it was.
The scene is one where  an adolescent boy visits his grandfather. The house the grandfather lives in is decrepit. I think the boy was forbidden to visit his grandfather. I also think the boy regularly used drugs and got into trouble more than once. In the scene, I believe his grandfather gives him some kind of psychedelic drug. The boy seems to go on a trip under the sand and when he comes back, he realises he died and came back. His grandfather was with him on the trip, but he did not come back; he's dead in his rocking chair.
One way or another, the boy's father realises what has happened and one way or another he seems to be relieved. It's as if he pardons the boy's past behaviour because of what happened at the grandfather's house.
The movie can't be very old, somewhere between 1995 and 2010.

FWIW, Wikipedia has an page on drug films. Perhaps you could find it there?
